# Can you put channels in a channel in Go?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

Can you create a channel of channels in Go???
example:

```
package main

func main() {

    c := make(chan chan int)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            c <- addChannel
        }

    }()
}
func addChannel() chan int {
    d := make(chan int)
    return d
}
```

I'm just curious, because this obviously could serve some purpose in go programming if it is possible.

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#chan_of_chan

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can; the [the language specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Channel_types) is a good place to start when you have questions like this.

However while it's possible to create a channel of channels it's not possible to create a channel without a "channel type". So in your code you should use `make(chan chan int)` that is a channel of channels of `int`. For example ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/XG-04eDj-2l)):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            c <- addChannel()
        }
        close(c)
    }()

    for ic := range c {
        for z := range ic {
            fmt.Println(z)
        }
        fmt.Println("done with channel")
    }
}
func addChannel() chan int {
    d := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        d <- 1
        close(d)
    }()
    return d
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Good to know.  I really probably should have checked the language spec, but I guess I was lazy and decided to ask the question when a simple google search failed.  Will definitely try to get in the habit of checking the docs as I move forward.